# Simplest way to calculate anniversary given a date in the past?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

i need a function that calculates if there is an upcoming anniversary for a person given a start date in the past and today's current date.  I found this code below but looking at the below code and I have the feeling that there is a much simpler way to calculate this without required this for loop:

```
private const int ANNIVERSARY_ALERT = 10;

public virtual string UpcomingMilestone
{
    get
    {
        var years = Years() + 2;
        for (int year = 0; year < years; year++)
        {
            int days = year * 365;
            int dayDiff = days - NumberOfDays;
            if (dayDiff == 0)
            {
                return year + " year milestone";
            }
            if (dayDiff < ANNIVERSARY_ALERT && dayDiff > 0)
            {
                return year + " year milestone in " + dayDiff + " days";
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public virtual int NumberOfDays
{
    get
    {
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Today - StartDate.Value;
        return (int)ts.TotalDays;
    }
}

public virtual int Years()
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartDate.Value);
    return (int)(span.Days / 365.25); // leap years included
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to calculate this above without having to do this loop?  This is more for code maintainability versus any performance considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the relevant parts of the startdate to compose a new DateTime:

```
//My birthday, feel free to put this date in your calendars!
var startDate = new DateTime(1976, 2, 29);

//Get the anniversary date for this year
DateTime nextAnniversary;

try
{
    nextAnniversary = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day);
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    //DateTime conversion failed, try next day in the year
    nextAnniversary = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, startDate.AddDays(1).Month, startDate.AddDays(1).Day);
}

//Check if this year's anniversary has already happened
if(nextAnniversary < DateTime.Today) nextAnniversary = nextAnniversary.AddYears(1);
```

Comment: it seems like this code will break if you have a start date on a leap year as nextAnniversary calculation will cause an exception

Comment: Indeed. So should the anniversary be every 4 years or push into 1st March?

Comment: I guess March 1st.  I am less concerned with missing these people compared to having the app blow up :)

Comment: It copes with leap years now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You need to provide `TimeSpan range` that can be a day or a week, and date which you are matching anniversary to.

```
    public bool Upcomming(DateTime date, TimeSpan range){
        var newdate = new Date(DateTime.Now.Year, date.Month, date.Day);
        return newdate - DateTime.Now < range;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this solves the question as you have to factor out the year here.  This below doesn't seem to do that (unless i am missing something)

Comment: @leora you are right in a rush I forgot to set year to current.

Answer (score 0):

```
int anniversaryYear = DateTime.Now.Year - StartDate.Year + 1;    

DateTime nextAnniversary = StartDate.AddYears(anniversaryYear);    

if (nextAnniversary == DateTime.Now)
{
    return anniverasryYear + " year milestone";
}

if (DateTime.Now > nextAnniverasry)
{
    anniverasryYear++;
    nextAnniversary = StartDate.AddYears(anniversaryYear);    
}

var daysTillNext = Math.Abs( (nextAnniversary - DateTime.Now).TotalDays );     
return string.Format("{0} milestone in {1}", anniversaryYear, daysTillNext);
```

Comment: seems like your answer has the same flaw as DavidG below.  The first line will blow up in certain cases like leap years as Feb 29th might not exist in the current year

Answer (score 0):

These methods should be sufficient for your purposes.

```
public DateTime GetNextAnniversaryDate(DateTime anniversary)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var year = anniversary.Month < today.Month || 
              (anniversary.Month == today.Month && anniversary.Day < today.Day)
        ? today.Year + 1 : today.Year;

    return anniversary.Month == 2 && anniversary.Day == 29 &&
           !DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)
        ? new DateTime(year, 2, 28)
        : new DateTime(year, anniversary.Month, anniversary.Day);
}

public int GetDaysUntilNextAnniversary(DateTime anniversary)
{
    var nextDate = GetNextAnniversaryDate(anniversary);
    return (int)(nextDate - DateTime.Today).TotalDays;
}
```

Note that we are specifically electing to celebrate leap-day anniversaries on Feb 28th when the anniversary year is not a leap year.  You could change that to March 1 if desired.

Also note that this question assumes that the day of the person in question is the same day as the computer's local clock.  This *might* not be true, for example if the local machine is in a time zone that is ahead of the user's time zone, then it might be one day off.  If you want to take that into consideration, then you could use `TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Or you could use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  [More about this on my blog](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/09/handling-birthdays-and-other-anniversaries/).